# VBA - I must use the code in sheet1 with a button in a sheet2

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my problem.
I have a sheet 1 named A, where I have some datas.
I have a sheet 2 named Macro, where I have a button.
I want to use this button to use my code on the sheet 1 (A).
But I can not use modules, I must use the sheet1 to my code...
[Here what I must use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IroWb.png)

But when i click on the button after attributing my code, it doesn't work and it show me that :
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgzpi.png)

It say : 
"the worksheet range or there is data in the table must be on the same worksheet"

Error defined by the application or the objectSo, my problem is : How can I use a button and the code on sheet1, on sheet2 ?

Here's the beginning of my code if it can help you :

```
Sub LinkToImage()

  Sheets("A").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$K$300"), , xlYes).Name = _
      "Tableau1"
  Range("Tableau1[#All]").Select
  Sheets("A").ListObjects("Tableau1").TableStyle = "TableStyleLight9"
  'Créé le tableau avec un style prédéfini.


  For Each cel In Range("k2", Range("k200").End(xlUp))
      cel.Offset(0, 1).Select
      cel.Offset(0, 1).RowHeight = 100 'Fixe la hauteur des cellules à 100
      cel.Offset(0, 1).ColumnWidth = 70 'Fixe la taille de la colonne à 40

      If IsFile(cel.Value) = 0 Then
         cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Photo non dispo" 'Si la photo n'est pas disponible, on affiche "Photo non dispo"
      Else
          Set image = Sheets("A").Pictures.Insert(cel.Value)
          With image
              .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
              .Width = cel.Offset(0, 1).Width
              .Height = cel.Offset(0, 1).Height
              .Left = cel.Offset(0, 1).Left + 5 'Laisse une marge à gauche de 5px
              .Top = cel.Offset(0, 1).Top + 5 'Laisse une marge en haut de 5px
              .Height = 90 'Fixe la hauteur de l'image à 90
              '.Height = 0.9 * cel.Offset(0, 1).Height
              '.Width = 0.5 * cel.Offset(0, 1).Width
              '.Right = cel.Offset(0, 1).Right +5
```

The error is on first line, do I think, it's because of `Sheets("A")`, but I don't know how to fix this...

Thank's in advance, and sorry for my english...

Comment: The error msg should explain it, you need to be on the same sheet as the table being created,

Comment: Yeah, I know, I search a solution to get around this error :/

Answer (score 0):

add a check on "Tableau1" existence as follows

```
Sub LinkToImage()
Dim table As ListObject

On Error Resume Next
Set table = Sheets("A").ListObjects("Tableau1")
On Error Resume Next
If table Is Nothing Then Set table = Sheets("A").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$B$1:$K$300"), , xlYes).Name = "Tableau1"

  Range("Tableau1[#All]").Select
  ...
```

Comment: I did, it create me two row on the sheet named "Macro", i don't understand why. I uploaded the real error message, it can help you ?

Comment: I wouldn't say since in my test it worked: I had a button in sheet "Macro" attached to sub `LinkToImage` residing in sheet "A" code pane. after clicking the button the macro would run and build "Tableau1" in sheet "A" as well as filling cell "L2" with "Photo non dispo" string. and then it ended since I had no data in column K of sheet "A" except string "Column1" in cell "K1"

Comment: Yeah, it's normal, because you put the code in sheet "A" code pane. In fact, my code must be in sheet "Macro" code pane

Comment: I see. Sorry for my misunderstanding. Now I better read Davesexcel comment. But what's keeping you from being able to write in a "normal" Module?. May be a workaround could be using VBE object model to write code in a new Module during the execution of the macro and have it run by the macro itself! But with no warranty...

Comment: In fact, one of my missions on my internship is to create a macro to create a layout for datas generates by the ERP. With the macro, datas will be in a table with a title, with images, and so on. And my boss created two sheets, one for the button, and commercials had just to push it to form datas, and one with datas. And I can't just us a normal Module because when the commercial need the new version of the datas, the module will not be in the new document... I hope you understand... ^^